# Whatsapp is cutting audio file when sharing it in android

Tags: android, whatsapp, android-sharing

I'm facing a problem when sharing an audio file which it's format is not mp3. the file is shared but with a shorter length for example if the file is 10 seconds it only shared 5 seconds.
if I used mp3 format it's shared completely, but other formats make the problem.

note: the file is shared without problem in other apps like messenger, also It shared without problem in android version 5.1

this is my code to share the audio file

```
    String content = //my file path on device "on external storage"
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("audio/*");

    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getString(R.string.file_provider_authority), new File(content));
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);


       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, context.getString(R.string.share)));
```

Also I don't want to change the file format to mp3, I need it to be in flac format

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: I am facing the same issue with a wav file. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: A solution has been offered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48550655/1426431