# Issues with android app sharing audio to facebook messenger and whatsapp

Tags: android, kotlin, share

I have an app where I am trying to share an mp3 file to email, messenger, whatsapp etc.

Everything works fine for email and whatsapp. However I'm having issues with facebook messenger. It seems that mp3 won't play on some devices (I think it is just iphones but I'm not 100% sure)

I tried converting my file from mp3 to wav and that seems to fix the problem for messenger, but then whatsapp seems to do really inconsistent things with wav files. See this: [Whatsapp is cutting audio file when sharing it in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53957441/whatsapp-is-cutting-audio-file-when-sharing-it-in-android)

So I'm stuck wanting to share as a wav when sharing to facebook and mp3 when sharing to whatsapp which I don't think is possible. What would you do in this situation?